# 405 Method Not Allowed - PUT (PHP)

Tags: php, api, .htaccess

I have problem with send a PUT request to my API. I got response:
"405 Method Not Allowed. The requested method PUT is not allowed for this URL."

in my htaccess I have:

```
<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
  Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Limit>
```

In php file I have:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    if (isset ($_GET['action']))
    {
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS')
        {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, DELETE, PUT');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin,x-csrftoken,content-Type');
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            die();
        }else
....
....
....
...
   } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT')
                if($action == 'update')
                {
                    $authResp = Auth::autorize($db, isset($_COOKIE['tkn']) ? $_COOKIE['tkn'] : null);
                    if($authResp->getCode() == 200){
                        $roomResp = menu::update($db, $data);
                        $authResp->addToMessage($roomResp->getMessage());
                    }
                    echo $authResp->genResponse();
                    die();                    
                }
```

How more I need to set, to allow PUT/DELETE methods?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your PHP, it's with your `.htaccess`; you have `<Limit GET POST OPTIONS>`. That *restricts* requests to *only* allow `GET`, `POST` or `OPTIONS`. If you additionally want to allow `PUT` and `DELETE`, you'll need to add these to the list of allowed methods:

`<Limit GET POST OPTIONS PUT DELETE>`

Comment: Is right, thanks, but I changed and still have same problem :/
I can see in my request in headers: Allow: HEAD,GET,POST,OPTIONS, but why? htaccess looks now good

Comment: after changes:

<Limit GET POST OPTIONS PUT DELETE>
  Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Limit>

still something is wrong :/